# Cannot drop Redshift user possibly due to UNKNOWN granted privilege

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to drop a user from a Redshift database but I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: user "user_1" cannot be dropped because permission dependency is found.

After checking all possible privileges assigned to the user (also using the utilities provided here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped), I could not find any permissions for this user, except for an entry in the svv_schema_privileges table:

`SELECT * FROM svv_schema_privileges`

namespace_name | privilege_type | identity_id | identity_name | identity_type | admin_option
schema_1       | UNKNOWN        | 11          | user_1        | user          | false

Now, there is no way I can remove the UNKNOWN privilege, since this does not exist and doing something like:

`REVOKE UNKNOWN ON SCHEMA schema_1 FROM user_1;`

does not work.

The user was granted permissions on the schema:

`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_1 TO user_1;`
`GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_1 TO user_1;`

These privileges were revoked with an equivalent statement:
`REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_1 FROM user_1;`
`REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_1 FROM user_1;`

I would appreciate any ideas and insights about this issues and a possible approach for a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This must be a redshift-only behavior, since that error message does not appear in the PostgreSQL source.